# What evidence do we have that dinosaurs were mesotherms?

Tags: dinosaurs

They went extinct millions of years ago, so what is the evidence supporting the claim that they were mesotherms? And are there any examples of modern-day mesotherms?

Comment: There are some examples in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesotherm).